# How to fix programmable thermostat to read temperature data from a web service?

Tags: java, json

I am currently having issues with my programmable thermostat application.  I run the app but do not get the required data back in a format that is acceptable.  These are the directions to my assignment and the code I use.

### Directions

Open your ProgrammableThermostat project in NetBeans, then write Java classes that employ standard Java coding conventions for building the display driver specified in the u03a1 User Story:

Part 1 – Create Classes and Build the Display Driver

Open your ProgrammableThermostat project in NetBeans, then write Java classes that employ standard Java coding conventions for building the display driver specified in the u03a1 User Story:

Do the following:

Your code will need to read temperature data stored in JSON format using a web service to access the JSON information stored on a Capella web server. You will create a web query to retrieve the data. The result of the query will be returned as JSON data. 
Develop Java networking classes/methods that read the temperature data from the web service.
Develop Java classes/methods that convert the raw temperature data into Java objects.
Build a driver to display the temperature data on the Java Console. Note the following:
You do not need to create a GUI; your data should be displayed in the NetBeans Java Console.

https://courserooma.capella.edu/bbcswebdav/institution/IT/IT4774/180100/Course_Files/cf_u03a1_user_story.docx

http://media.capella.edu/BBCourse_Production/IT4774/temperature.json

I already have the json-simple 1.1.1 and the org.json package.

My code:

```
package programmable.thermostat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;


public class ProgrammableThermostat {

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException, org.json.simple.parser.ParseException{

    //Need to string info to initialize variable for later use
    String info = null;

    //Here we have the http of the site that was given to us
    URL url = new URL("http://media.capella.edu/BBCourse_Production/IT4774/temperature.json");

    //Forms an http connection to the URL called conn and opens it
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    //sets get request type
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //Opens connection to API
    conn.connect();

    //Gets the response code for format
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

    //if response code not 200 throws runtime exception
    if(responseCode != 200)
        throw new RuntimeException("HttpResponseCode: " +responseCode);
    /* else the scanner opens the URL stream and reads in the code line by line*/
    else
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(url.openStream());
        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            info += sc.nextLine();
        }
            System.out.println("JSON data in string format!");
            System.out.println(info);
            sc.close();
    }

    JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject)parse.parse(info);
    JSONArray thermostatInfo = (JSONArray)object.get("results");

    //get data for results array
    for(int i = 0; i < thermostatInfo.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject_1 = (JSONObject)thermostatInfo.get(i);
        System.out.println("Items in result array!");
        System.out.println("Identifier: " + jsonObject_1.get("identifier"));
        System.out.println("\nName: " + jsonObject_1.get("name"));
        System.out.println("\nThermostat Time: " + jsonObject_1.get("thermostatTime"));
        System.out.println("\nutcTime: " + jsonObject_1.get("utcTime"));
        System.out.println("\nRuntime: " + jsonObject_1.get("runtime"));
        System.out.println("\nStatus: " + jsonObject_1.get("status"));
    }
}

}
```

There are two expected results of doing this project.  To Read each line of the JSON data and parse it out to different values for displaying.  The second part is to display the data nicely on the screen.

The output of my application is:

```
JSON data in string format!
null{    "identifier": "318324702718",    "name": "ProgrammableThermostat",    "thermostatTime": "2015-02-11 15:58:03",    "utcTime": "2015-02-11 20:58:03",    "runtime": {        "actualTemperature": 711,        "actualHumidity": 42,    },    "status": {        "code": 0,        "message": ""    }}                                     
Exception in thread "main" Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({) at position 4.
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:146)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:81)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:75)
at programmable.thermostat.ProgrammableThermostat.main(ProgrammableThermostat.java:52)
C:\Users\Deb\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: "Develop Java networking classes/methods...", you are doing everything in `main()`?

Comment: When I add Java classes and methods then I get run with no output on screen

Comment: Then you have some way to go since it looks like it is required. Look at the documentation for the json packages you have because I am sure there is an easier way to get the json message than using the Scanner class.

Answer (score 0):

Despite doing everything in the main() method, which your task I guess tries to avoid, your problem isn't in your code.

It is with the web service itself. If you access the URL you use with your browser (I did it with Firefox) you can see the same error that your Java console is telling you: the format of the JSON is not correct:
[image: JSON Error]

I hope this can help you!

Comment: It kind of does but when I try it on chrome it comes out just fine.

Comment: Chrome does not have by default a JSON parser/validator. If you don't trust Firefox either, you can also try to validate the JSON you get with a tool like https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Either it is part of the assignment to fix this or OP has to contact the teacher or who ever owns the assignment. I can confirm that the json is wrong but this isn't really an answer to the question

Comment: Your question does not have a 'normal' answer where I would tell you how to accomplish your school tasks. But you can't fix a wrong JSON coming from a Server (or, at least, you shouldn't). What you can still do is try to accomplish all the tasks related with code style such as create classes and methods, instead of putting all your code in the main. I don't know if this is the answer you want, but don't expect a interesting answer to a stupid question.

Comment: Specifically, you should tell your professor that the JSON is mal-formed because there's an extra comma after `"actualHumidity": 42` - with that comma removed, it becomes valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing your data variable to `null`. When you start appending the JSON to the variable, you get `null{json stuff here}`. Initialize it to the empty string instead:

```java
String data = "";
```